# Clarification needed regarding basic indexer and collection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm going through another developer's code, which is shown below:

```
[XmlElement("AdminRecipient")] public AdminRecipient[] AdminRecipientCollection = new AdminRecipient[0];

        public AdminRecipient this[ string type ]
        {
            get
            {
                AdminRecipient result = null;
                foreach( AdminRecipient emailRecipient in AdminRecipientCollection )
                {
                    if( emailRecipient.Type == type )
                    {
                        result = emailRecipient;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return( result );
            }
```

Can someone explain what's going to happen in this line?

```
public AdminRecipient[] AdminRecipientCollection = new AdminRecipient[0];
```

The XML file that contains all of the email recipients has about 5 email addresses. But by using [0], will the foreach loop return each of those email addresses?

I have a basic understanding of indexers, but I don't this. What does it do?:

```
public AdminRecipient this[ string type ]
```

At the end of the day, the problem here is that the application doesn't send out an email when all 5 recipients are in the xml file. If I replace the 5 addresses with just 1 email addresses, then I'm able to get the email (which leads me to believe that there's a logic issue somewhere here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An indexer allows you to use a type with the same syntax as array access. One of the simplest examples would be `List<T>`:

```
List<string> x = new List<string>();
x.Add("Item 0");
x.Add("Item 1");

string y = x[0]; // "Item 0"
```

That use of `x[0]` is calling the indexer for `List<T>`. Now for `List<T>` the index is an integer, as it is for an array, but it doesn't have to be. For example, with `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` it's the key type:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("foo", "bar");

string fetched = dictionary["foo"]; // fetched = "bar"
```

You can have a "setter" on an indexer too:

```
dictionary["a"] = "b";
```

Your indexer is just returning the first `AdminRecipient` in the array with a matching type - or null if no match can be found.

(It's unfortunate that the code you've shown is also using a public field, by the way. It would be better as a property - and probably not an array, either. But that's a separate discussion.)

EDIT: Regarding the first line you highlighted:

```
public AdminRecipient[] AdminRecipientCollection = new AdminRecipient[0];
```

That will create an array with no elements, and assign a reference to the `AdminRecipientCollection` field. With no further changes, the `foreach` loop would not have anything to iterate over, and the indexer will always return null.

However, presumably something else - such as XML serialization - is assigning a different value to that field - populating it with more useful data.

Comment: I don't believe the actual problem is understading an indexer but instead it's about confusing an array initialization with use of an indexer. Take a looke at the line of code OP has highlighted

Comment: @Rune FS: I looked that the *second* line of code he highlighted, but not the first much. Have edited to talk about that too.

Comment: @Jon: how you make time for such detailed answers is anyone's guess, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The line you're asking about is an assignment of `AdminRecipientCollection` to an empty array.  This assignment will occur at instantiation time.  The deserialization of the XML will happen *after* the class is instantiated, if ever.  The author's purpose here is presumably to ensure that `AdminRecipientCollection` will never be null, even in case the class is used before XML is deserialized into it.

By ensuring that `AdminRecipientCollection` is never null, the author can ignore the possibility that the foreach loop will throw a NullReferenceException.  At least, that's probably the hope.

Unfortunately, because `AdminRecipientCollection` is public, the `AdminRecipient` property could still throw, as in the following case:

```
var demoClass = new DemoClass();
demoClass.AdminRecipientCollection = null;
var firstRecipient = demoClass[0];
```

To prevent this possibility, remove the initial assignment and check for null in the `AdminRecipient` property before beginning the enumeration.